# Execute query in SQL Developer, Executing it in IBM BPM Server Script

Tags: sql, sqlcommand, business-process-management

When I execute that query in SQL Developer it works, but when I try executing it in IBM BPM Server Script I get this Error "SQL command not properly ended", Why is that?

That's my Query

```
tw.local.sql = "SELECT Extract(MONTH FROM TRAININGDB.USERDETAILS2.DATEOFBIRTH), COUNT (TRAININGDB.USERDETAILS2.DATEOFBIRTH) FROM TRAININGDB.USERDETAILS2GROUP BY Extract(MONTH FROM TRAININGDB.USERDETAILS2.DATEOFBIRTH)";
```

Comment: add a semicolon `;` before the `"` after the `)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of your cut/paste of the code, you are missing a space before the "GROUP BY" -

> ... FROM TRAININGDB.USERDETAILS2GROUP BY...

-AP